# IDE on Host Windows Machine, Project on RHEL Hyper V

Tags: java, windows-10, rhel, hyper-v

Fresh out of uni, so a lot of the basic practical stuff is new to me. I apologize in advance.

I just got started at a company and the company laptop I received is running windows 10, but all of the company projects are intended to run on RHEL. I was told by my group that the choice of w10 for the laptop was a poor decision that is ultimately out of their (read: my) hands.

The veterans of my group assure me that coding without an IDE is not practical in a real world environment, so off I go to grab myself an IDE.

I've gotten RHEL running over Hyper-V, and its perfectly possible for me to just download Eclipse into the vm and start coding away, but the input lag on the vm's GUI makes the whole experience pretty clunky.

So basically, **I need to use an IDE. All of the project files are stored on a virtual machine. Is there any setup I could employ to avoid using a GUI running from the VM itself?**

Google suggested "Remote System Explorer" with Eclipse, but all of the search results are from a decade ago and some forums even state that RSE doesn't work with the current versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Whats the programming language that you are going to use in your day to day project tasks or work? JetBrains has a good set of IDEs you can start with. assuming your organization is paying for the license. https://www.jetbrains.com

Comment: Then IntelliJ IDEA will be a good option

Answer (score 0):

OP here: opting for vs code with the "remote development" extension. There are probably other solutions, but this one was the first one that I was able to confirm actually did what I wanted to - application runs from my local machine so there's no vm-GUI delay, but with the project residing on a different machine.